# Python 2.7 .lower() function combined with .replace

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to combine .lower() and .replace but im struggling.

here is my code snippet...

```
elif "rename account 1 " in msg.text:
    if msg.from_ in Admin:
                string = msg.text.replace("rename account 1 ","")
```

this looks for user issuing the command 'rename account 1' and then in the same string adding the new name eg. 'rename account 1 account 2'

the trouble is if a user inputs any capital letters, eg. 'Rename Account 1' the command is not recognised.
What I normally to do is use the .lower() to change the input string to all lowercase and then match the command which is all lowercase.
 The problem is if I do that, the .replace can only be all lowercase as well.

I can do this...

```
elif "rename account 1 " in msg.text.lower():
    if msg.from_ in Admin:
                string = msg.text.lower().replace("rename account 1 ","")
```

which solves the problem of the input, but adds the problem of the output being all lowercase.
How can I isolate the 2 things in this case?

I am new to python and learning on the fly, so if the answer is obvious please forgive me.

Thanks

Comment: Is whatever system you are targeting case sensitive? Does it make a difference if the resulting command is ``rename account 1 account 2`` versus ``Rename Account 1 Account 2``? Also, it sounds like ``account 1`` is not a fixed string but may vary depending on input: is this correct?

Comment: no its not case sensitive, the user knows the command to call function, but the user wont always input all lowercase etc. I am just purely trying to make the matching easier on the user without forcing the output result to lowercase as well. The input string will always be 'rename account 1' with the following text in the string being what they want the new name to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to replace a string case insensitively.

```
import re

text = 'ALPHA,Rename ACCOUNT 1,beta'
string = re.sub('rename account 1', '', text, flags=re.I)
print(string)
```

Result:

```
ALPHA,,beta
```

The [`re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I) flag is short for "ignore case".

Comment: Thanks I managed to implement this and have it do exactly what I want.